# Vector multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix-multiplication, numerical-analysis

Let **A,B** be matrixes of R^n space and **b** belong to R^n.Describe a fast algorithm to compute A^-2*B*A^-3*b.How many computations will the algorithm make?

This is an exam question I have for numerical analysis.I tried brute forcing an algorithm but i believe that the answer is more mathematical.

We haven't yet talked about Big O notations so the question asks for strictly the actions of the algorithm.How would you go about answering this question?

Comment: This might be better answered on one of the more math or CS oriented SE sites.

Comment: Hint: As matrix product is associative, proceed multiplying the given entities _from right to left_ to get the answer in O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

I would just work the problem from right to left, using a linear solver when dealing with the inverse of A, and matrix multiply when dealing with B:

```
x1 = linsolve(A, b)
x2 = linsolve(A, x1)
x3 = linsolve(A, x2)
y = B*x3
z1 = linsolve(A,y)
result = linsolve(A,z1)
```

You can reduce by a constant multiplier the number of operations by keeping the LU decomposition of A in memory, but unless you are given more structure on A and B, quadratic complexity seems to be the best you can aim for.